# Baffled with calculating $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{(2xe^x-2e^x+1)}$

Tags: limits

> Given $$f(x)=2(x-1)e^x+1$$
>
> Find: $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}$

**Personal work:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{(2xe^x-2e^x+1)}=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}({e^x \over 1/2x}-2e^x+1)$$... Gets to nowhere. Also, subtituing yields no results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x\Big(2x-2+\frac{1}{e^x}\Big)=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(2x-2+\frac{1}{e^x}\Big)=\infty,$$ since the limit of $e^x$ is $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What happens with $(x-1)e^x$ when $x$ is too big?

Comment: $\forall x>1, (x-1)e^x>0$

Comment: For $x=+\infty$ it is $+\infty$

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis: that's right! So, your answer is?

Comment: Well, $+\infty$!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write the term in the form
$$xe^x\left(2-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{xe^x}\right)$$

Comment: Factorizing the dominant term is always a good choice when in the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

What is: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x=\dots\tag{1}$$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^x=\dots\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}2(x-1)e^x=\infty.
$$
(Why?)